# Time overlap issue javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am working in add task module in my project.i want to check every time task add check if existing tasks overlap or not. i am almost did but,one problem occur on time overlap condition not allow add task, example if user add tasks below times like below:

> 09:00 AM - 10:00 AM
>
> 10:30 AM - 11:00 AM

if i add tasks to between 10:00 AM to 10:30 AM not allowed in my condition on below:

```
function disabletime(start_time, end_time) {
    var start_date = new Date(new Date(start_time).getTime());
    var end_date = new Date(new Date(end_time).getTime());

    var disable_times = new Array();
    var max_date = 0;
    var min_date = 0;

    if (tasks_array.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks_array.length; i++) {

            var prev_s_date = Date.parse("1-1-2000 " + tasks_array[i].start_time);
            var prev_e_date = Date.parse("1-1-2000 " + tasks_array[i].end_time);
            var prev_start_date = new Date(new Date(prev_s_date).getTime());
            var prev_end_date = new Date(new Date(prev_e_date).getTime());
            if (i == 0) {
                min_date = prev_start_date.getTime();
                max_date = prev_end_date.getTime();
            } else {

                if (prev_end_date.getTime() > max_date) {
                    max_date = prev_end_date.getTime();
                }

                if (prev_start_date.getTime() < min_date) {
                    min_date = prev_start_date.getTime();
                }
            }
        }
        if ((start_date.getTime() == min_date) && (end_date.getTime() == max_date)) {
            alert("Check the start and end time for this task!");
            return false;
        } else if ((start_date.getTime() < min_date) && (end_date.getTime() <= min_date) || (start_date.getTime() >= max_date) && (end_date.getTime() > max_date)) {

        } else {
            alert("Check the start and end time for this task!");
            return false;

        }
    }
    start_date = new Date(start_date.getTime() + 30 * 60000);
    while (start_date < end_date) {
        disable_times.push([start_date.getHours(), start_date.getMinutes()]);
        start_date = new Date(start_date.getTime() + 30 * 60000);
    }

    return true;
}
```

here is my code flow, i add all tasks into json array in javascript. every time add new task check existing tasks on json array objects(inside if tasks exist) time overlap or not.

**[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b68Qa/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got solution from my friends on below code:

```
function disabletime(start_time, end_time) {
    var start_date = start_time;
    var end_date = end_time;

    var disable_times = new Array();
    var max_date = 0;
    var min_date = 0;

    var startTimeOverlapIndex = -1;
    var endTimeOverlapIndex = -1;
    var sameDateIndex = -1;

    if (tasks_array.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks_array.length; i++) {
            var prev_s_date = new Date("January 1, 1111 " + tasks_array[i].start_time);
            var prev_e_date = new Date("January 1, 1111 " + tasks_array[i].end_time);

            if(end_date<=prev_e_date) {
                if(end_date>prev_s_date) {
                    endTimeOverlapIndex = i+1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(start_date<prev_e_date) {
                if(start_date>=prev_s_date) {
                    startTimeOverlapIndex = i+1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if(end_date>prev_s_date) {
                        endTimeOverlapIndex = i+1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(start_date.toString()===prev_s_date.toString() && end_date.toString()===prev_e_date.toString()) {
                sameDateIndex = i+1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(sameDateIndex>0) {
            alert("Sorry! your time cannot be same as task ("+startTimeOverlapIndex+"), please check again!");
            return false;
        } else if(startTimeOverlapIndex>0) {
            alert("Sorry! your START time is overlaping with task ("+startTimeOverlapIndex+"), please check again!");
            return false;
        } else if(endTimeOverlapIndex>0) {
            alert("Sorry! your END time is overlaping with task ("+endTimeOverlapIndex+"), please check again!");
            return false;
        } else {
            //do whatever you do
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Live link on fiddle find here

http://jsfiddle.net/mur7H/

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a 'refactor if you want to debug' case.
Just breaking you problems into well isolated, small, simple problems will lead you to a solution faster than any deep debug cession.
You should break down the complexity of your code by using objects, 
so you'll have a clear view on who does what, and you can test
easily each part.
I'm not sure the code below complies with all your needs, but it
should be much easier to use : i defined 2 objects : a task,
and a set of task.
For each i defined pretty simple methods, easy to read and debug.

I did not test the result, but you'll get the idea on how to do what
you want from here.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/b68Qa/2/

```
// ------------------------------  
// Task
function Task(startDate, endDate) {
    this.start = startDate;
    this.end = endDate;
}

// returns wether the time range overlaps with this task
Task.prototype.overlap = function (start, end) {
    return (this.start <= end && this.end >= start);
}

// returns a string describing why the task is wrong, or null if ok
function checkTask(start, end) {
    if (start > end) return "End time should exceed the start time";
    if (start == end) return "End time should not same as the start time";
    return null;
}
```

and now a set of tasks :

```
// ------------------------------  
// Task Set
function TaskSet() {
    this.tasks = [];
    this.minDate = 0;
    this.maxDate = 0;
}

// returns a string describing why the task cannot be added, or null if ok
TaskSet.prototype.check = function (start, end) {
    var tasks = this.tasks;
    // 1. Check date is valid
    var dateCheck = checkTask(start, end);
    if (dateCheck) return dateCheck;
    // 2. overlap check
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        var thisTask = tasks[i];
        if (thisTask.overlap(start, end)) {
            return 'time overlaps with another task';
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// add the task.
TaskSet.prototype.add = function (start, end) {
    var tasks = this.tasks;
    if (task.length) {
        this.minDate = start;
        this.maxDate = end;
    }
    if (start < minDate) minDate = start;
    if (end > maxDate) maxDate = end;
    // you might want to check before inserting.
    tasks.push(new Task(start, end));
}

// displays the current task inside the tasks div.
TaskSet.prototype.show = function () {
    var tasks_array = this.tasks;
    $("#tasks").html('');
    $.each(tasks_array, function (index, item) {
        var newRowContent = "<div>" + item.start_time + "-" + item.end_time + "</div>";
        $("#tasks").append(newRowContent);
    });
}
```

Let's use those objects :

```
// ---------------------------
var myTasks = new TaskSet();


$("#addtask").click(handle_AddTask_Clicked);

function handle_AddTask_Clicked(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var start = $("#task_stime").val();
    var end = $("#task_etime").val();

    var start_time = Date.parse("1-1-2000 " + start);
    var end_time = Date.parse("1-1-2000 " + end);

    var checkCanAdd = myTasks.check(start_time, end_time);
    if (!checkCanAdd) {
        myTasks.add(start_time, end_time);
        myTasks.show(); // notice you might auto-refresh withinin add
    } else {
        alert(checkCanAdd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is 100% working. Please find below the correct answer with date and time overlapping.

```
function isBetween(ST, ET, PST, PET) {
    var res = false;
    if (((ST - PST) * (ST - PET) <= 0) || ((ET - PST) * (ET - PET) <= 0) || ((PST - ST) * (PST - ET) <= 0) || ((PET - ST) * (PET - ET) <= 0)) res = true;
    return res;
}

function disabletime(start_time, end_time) {
    debugger;
    var start_date = new Date(start_time);
    var end_date = new Date(end_time);
    var disable_times = new Array();
    var max_date = 0;
    var min_date = 0;
    var startTimeOverlapIndex = -1;
    var endTimeOverlapIndex = -1;
    var sameDateIndex = -1;
    var resultA = true;
    if (KitchenHourList.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < KitchenHourList.length; i++) {
            var prev_s_date = new Date(KitchenHourList[i].KitchenFromDate + " " + KitchenHourList[i].KitchenFromTime);
            var prev_e_date = new Date(KitchenHourList[i].KitchenToDate + " " + KitchenHourList[i].KitchenToTime);
            var STMinut = (start_date.getHours() * 60) + start_date.getMinutes();
            var ETMinut = (end_date.getHours() * 60) + end_date.getMinutes();
            var PSTMinut = (prev_s_date.getHours() * 60) + prev_s_date.getMinutes();
            var PETMinut = (prev_e_date.getHours() * 60) + prev_e_date.getMinutes();
            if (end_date <= prev_e_date) {
                if (end_date > prev_s_date) {
                    if (isBetween(STMinut, ETMinut, PSTMinut, PETMinut)) {
                        endTimeOverlapIndex = i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (start_date < prev_e_date) {
                if (start_date >= prev_s_date) {
                    if (isBetween(STMinut, ETMinut, PSTMinut, PETMinut)) {
                        startTimeOverlapIndex = i + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (end_date > prev_s_date) {
                        if (isBetween(STMinut, ETMinut, PSTMinut, PETMinut)) {
                            {
                                endTimeOverlapIndex = i + 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (start_date.toString() === prev_s_date.toString() && end_date.toString() === prev_e_date.toString()) {
                sameDateIndex = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sameDateIndex > 0) {
            alert("Sorry! your time cannot be same as row (" + startTimeOverlapIndex + "), please check again!");
            return false;
        } else if (startTimeOverlapIndex > 0) {
            alert("Sorry! your START time is overlaping with row (" + startTimeOverlapIndex + "), please check again!");
            return false;
        } else if (endTimeOverlapIndex > 0) {
            alert("Sorry! your END time is overlaping with row (" + endTimeOverlapIndex + "), please check again!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```